# Convert [postposition]/[postpositions] to [particle]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

I think [particle](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/particle) fits better than [postposition](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/postposition)/[postpositions](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/postpositions) for the translation of the word “조사.” The word “postposition” means a somewhat different thing:

> a word or morpheme placed after the word it governs, for example “-ward” in “homeward.”

Comment: Looks like [postposition] doesn't exist as a tag. [postpositions] is currently present on 5 questions (and has no tag usage guidance), whereas [particle] is on 47 questions (and does have tag usage guidance).